# Android Studio 3.1.2 : Failed to resolve: runtime

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

I have recently updated my Android Studio to 3.1.2 . After the update I tried opening the existing project and was shown multiple gradle errors while compiling the project.

Those errors pointed me to update the **'compile'** statement to **'implementation'**, which I did, still faced some errors which I later solved by **updating my google play and firebase sdks** to **latest version**.

Now I have no clue why is my IDE giving the following error (look at the screenshot).

**Failed to resolve: runtime**

[image]).

Now when I did **Build > Clean Project**

The error was **Could not find runtime.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.3).**
Screen shot 
[image]

What to do next?

**SOLUTION:**

1. I updated all my google play services and firebase libs.
2. To solve could not find runtime aar, I just simply arranged the **google()** on top in repositories.

Comment: post your app gradle

Comment: It seems like it cannot get this .aar file, did you make sure you have internet connection

Comment: I do have good internet connection and upon syncing gradle it is fetching all the files properly.

Comment: @KoustuvGanguly what part do you need from my gradle file.

Comment: I've got same problem when run the build with jenkins. After rearrange the repo, it worked for me

Comment: i have to add google() on top in repositories build.gradle(Project) .
in every repositories tag

Answer (score 64):

yes ,

If you are getting error like error run time  you can change the position of google() in dependencies in build. gradle.. Like below:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
```

Comment: This worked for me after I changed the order in `allprojects { repositories {`, not `buildscript { repositories {` which I changed first.

Comment: This also worked for me.
It was working on `Android Studio 3.0.1`, but not on `Android Studio 3.1.2`

I had to add `google()` as first in the `allprojects { repositories { google() ... } }`

Comment: Worked for me.. but can someone please explain why does it even work. They can create this awesome Android Studio, but these type of silly things they can not tackle with?

Comment: this is what its really like to be an android developer. having to figure these things out. what a waste of time

Answer (score 6):

`android.arch.lifecycle:runtime` is available at the google maven repository. Make sure you add the repository in the repositories block of your `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

or

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Reference :
[Adding Components to your Project](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components)

Comment: I tried rearranging google, got rid of the error , but now getting a different one, The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Comment: This you cant do anything for now!

Answer (score 5):

Please follow this as same (sequentially) in build.gradle (project: projectName) and issue will be gone

```
buildscript {

repositories { // keep same this order
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    // can add your other compile types here
    }
}

allprojects { // keep same this order
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` as first entry in a`llprojects/repositories` in top level `build.gradle`

like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```