# Error:Failed to resolve: runtime

Tags: android-studio

so my project was working fine yesterday and I tried to open it today and it gives me that error , help would be much appreciated
I tried to search for a long time about whats going wrong but it seems all answers not working with me

Error:Failed to resolve: runtime
Open File

here is build.gradle(Project) file:

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here is build app profile

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.writer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 16):

Based on the answer in [Android Studio 3.1.2 : Failed to resolve: runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50584437/android-studio-3-1-2-failed-to-resolve-runtime), try changing the order of imports in build.gradle project file as

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I encountered this problem as well with a gradle file of a submodule, and this answer worked.
For me, Android Studio said "Failed to resolve: common" as well as "Failed to resolve: runtime"

Answer (score 1):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

You must place `google()` as the 1st line. Reminder First line. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is very weird and took me almost 4-5 hours to fix. But, it turns out you need to put `google()` at the top and `jcenter()` at the bottom of repositories in build files for all modules. Maven can go in between and it'll be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
repositories {
    google()`Goolge repo`
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/ `Google maven repo`
        name 'Google'
    }

}
```