# Travis CI build failed, Could not resolve all files for configuration

Tags: android, travis-ci

I suddenly experience build failure with TRAVIS CI builds. But build succeeded with my local project. And the code has never been changed.

The link below shows error. `{"errors": [{"status": 404,"message": "Could not find resource"}]}`

> :library:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :myapp:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong: Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':hwahae:debugCompileClasspath'.
>
> > Could not find firebase-core.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1).
>
> Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/12.0.1/firebase-core-12.0.1.jar
>
> > Could not find play-services-ads.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1).
>
> Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/12.0.1/play-services-ads-12.0.1.jar
>
> > Could not find play-services-auth.jar
>   (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1).   Searched in the
>   following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/12.0.1/play-services-auth-12.0.1.jar
>
> * Try:
>
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
>   or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
>   insights.
>
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 29s 64
>   actionable tasks: 16 executed, 48 up-to-date

myapp.gradle

```
dependencies {
    def firebase_version 12.0.1
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$firebase_version"
    def google_service_version = '12.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$google_service_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$google_service_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$google_service_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$google_service_version"
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue since this morning. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50790391/2243928) worked for me

Comment: @Shazvi Suddenly build succeeded this morning... In my build.gradle, `google()` is not on top of `repositories`, but I can't test your suggestion because build succeeded. thanks.